Establecer un textview que solo tenga saltos de línea cuando el texto lo indique
Como dice el título, necesito hacer un textview que tiene tamaño de letra adaptable y puede tener varios saltos de linea, pero quiero que estos saltos de línea solo estén presentes cuando sean parte del texto "\n"
El problema creo que es que el textview está en una ContraintLayout que está vinculada a otro textView mas chico. ¿Existe la forma de establecer que solo permita saltos de linea cuando lo especifique el texto?
Dejo el código:
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/titulo"
        style="@style/textTitleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_padding_medium"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_padding_medium"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_padding_xxlarge"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_padding_medium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/recurso_string"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texto"
        style="@style/textTitleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding_small"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="@dimen/text_large2"
        android:autoSizeMinTextSize="@dimen/text_medium"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/titulo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/titulo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/titulo"
        tools:text="Texto largo sin saltos de linea" />


Lo solucioné agregando un margen negativo al xml, quedó así:
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texto"
        style="@style/textTitleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding_small"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="@dimen/text_large2"
        android:autoSizeMinTextSize="@dimen/text_medium"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:layout_marginStart="-45dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-45dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/titulo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/titulo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/titulo"
        tools:text="Texto largo sin saltos de linea" />

